# make progress bar background transparent

Tags: android, android-progressbar, android-dialog

This is the output i am getting.

[image]

as you can see the progress bar has white borders that i cant get rid off. I want the loading to jus comprise of the beige ball and the custom animation inside it. I used a dialog for this.

below is my code:

ActivityIndicator extends the dialog.

```
public class ActivityIndicator extends Dialog {

    private ProgressBar progressBar;

    public ActivityIndicator(@NonNull Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_indicator);
        this.setCancelable(false);

        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        ThreeBounce threeBounce = new ThreeBounce();
        progressBar.setIndeterminateDrawable(threeBounce);
    }



}
```

ThreeBounce is a custom library that i imported for the animation.

activityIndicator.xml :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">


<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="@drawable/loading_ball>
</ProgressBar>


<com.github.ybq.android.spinkit.SpinKitView xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/spin_kit"
    style="@style/SpinKitView.ThreeBounce"
    android:layout_width="68dp"
    android:layout_height="59dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/loading_ball"
    app:SpinKit_Color="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

loading_ball.xml:(Custom circle image view)

```
 <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/loadingball"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/circle"/>

</layer-list>
```

circle.xml:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:innerRadius="1.5dp"
    android:shape="ring"
    android:thicknessRatio="1.9"
    android:useLevel="false" >
    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />

    <stroke
        android:width="0dp"
        android:color="@android:color/white" />
</shape>
```

i tried setting the progress bar background to transparent but it doesnt seem to work. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: what is your `@drawable/loadingball`

Comment: Try add `getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);`

Comment: @gianhtran drawable/loadingball is the loading ball image imported from sketch. sorry for naming confusions

Comment: are you sure that the background of 'loadingball' is transparent ?

Comment: yeap actually @SohnLab u fixed my problem. Thanks for everyone's reply also !

Comment: Glad to help you @calveeen :D

Answer (score 0):

First create a class Loader

```
public class Loader extends Dialog{

 public Loader(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public Loader(Context context, int theme) {
    super(context, theme);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    setContentView(R.layout.loader_layout);
}

public Loader(Context context, boolean cancelable,
              OnCancelListener cancelListener) {
    super(context, cancelable, cancelListener);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
```

}

and it's Layout

```
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:background="#00ffffff">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#00ffffff"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

    <com.github.ybq.android.spinkit.SpinKitView 
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/spin_kit"
        style="@style/SpinKitView.ThreeBounce"
        android:layout_width="68dp"
        android:layout_height="59dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/loading_ball"
        app:SpinKit_Color="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and Call the loader by this method

```
 Loader loader = new Loader(this,android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar);
loader.show();
loader.setCancelable(false);
loader.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
```